# Wilks' test applied to trinomial data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

Has anyone heard of a Wilks' trinomial significance test before?

I'm trying to decipher an old approach with little documentation that was used in a product preference study (i.e., prefer product A, prefer product B, No preference) that employed a PBIB (partially balanced incomplete block) design.

The main thing I'm having difficulty on is that they've referenced a "Wilks' trinomial" test that was used for significance testing.  Not only have I never heard of it, but apparently neither has the internet....nothing comes up in searches.

Any guidance/direction on this...literally *anything* would be very helpful. :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilks%27s_lambda_distribution perhaps?

Comment: It is Wilks and not Wilke.

Comment: As Carl has pointed out you can find it as Wilks lambda even on wikipedia.